# Filtering of values using a small databases instead of settings.xml in maven

Tags: java, maven-2

Correct me if I'm wrong but one normally puts deployment or user-specific properties (e.g. development/testserver settings) inside settings.xml. And by specifying which profiles to use, we can change the behaviour of the maven build.

However there are usually settings in the profiles (settings.xml) which should be shared. Since I don't want to check in settings.xml, I want the maven build to query a database for those profile settings & do the filtering. Is this possible via some plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Correct me if I'm wrong but one normally puts deployment or user-specific properties (e.g. development/testserver settings) inside settings.xml. And by specifying which profiles to use, we can change the behaviour of the maven build.

Well, `settings.xml` is not the best choice for profiles if you don't want to  make your build non portable. You should actually put profiles in the `pom.xml` of your project instead and use `settings.xml` for "secret" things only. See chapter [11.5. Tips and Tricks](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/profiles-sect-tips-tricks.html) of Sonatype's Maven book. Actually, I'd suggest to read the whole chapter [11. Build Profiles](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/profiles.html).

> However there are usually settings in the profiles (settings.xml) which should be shared. Since I don't want to check in settings.xml, I want the maven build to query a database for those profile settings & do the filtering. Is this possible via some plugin ?

Well, as I said, putting the profiles in the `pom.xml` should solve this (and I don't know if such a plugin exists). An intermediary solution would be to use profiles and [filters](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html) as described in [this blog post](http://mybiblebook.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!8D4E97688DE1E193!445.entry) but this isn't much different.